# GeoPandas sjoin speedup

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I am using GeoPandas's `sjoin` function to join 2 dataframes: `dataframeA` has latitude and longitude information whereas `dataframeB` has polygon information. Number of rows in `dataframeA` may vary (~70M) but are the same for `dataframeB` (825k). I want to perform point in polygon operation and update `dataframeA` with information from `dataframeB`. Here is my code which works (`rtree` and `libspatialindex` has been installed):

```
dataframeB = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dataFromReadCSV,crs="EPSG:4326",geometry=geometry)    
dataframeA = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dataframeA,crs="EPSG:4326",geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(dataframeA.longitude, dataframeA.latitude))
dataframeA = gpd.sjoin(dataframeA, dataframeB, op='within', how='left')
```

Since the memory requirement for this task is [very high](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/955), I chunk `dataFrameA` before `sjoin` and append the results from disk. This process has been working fine.

Environment: Python 3.6; Dask - for high performance cluster

Problem: For chunked `dataframeA` (~7-8M rows), it takes about 2-3 hrs. I know point in polygon is computationally expensive.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried dividing the polygons into smaller pieces?

Comment: No, I have not tried that as it would increase number of point in polygon computations. Have you experienced improved performance doing so?

Comment: Indeed, complex polygons are quite costly for point-in-polygon (which is O(N^2) for #vertices). There exists an optimal "sweet spot" where number of polygons isn't too high, but number of vertices is low enough. You might also try inverting the query to search B,A instead of A,B (though the results can be slightly different)

Comment: I will try this. Any pointers on efficiently dividing polygons? One challenge I can think of is that the polygons are of different sizes - city, town, village, mall, business center, standalone business, etc. Would you still advise dividing the polygons in this case?

Comment: None of those things sounds like they're large (think coastlines of Russia, Canada, US or Australia with millions of vertices -- see https://community.esri.com/people/vangelo-esristaff/blog/2014/09/15/partitioning-large-geometries-to-improve-query-performance). In fact, I haven't seen such poor performance in decades, though searching indexed points with polys will help, you should make sure that your indexing was done correctly.

Comment: You can get significant speedup if you have GeoPandas 0.8 and `pygeos` installed (https://geopandas.org/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency).

Comment: @martinfleis including pygeos has certainly improved the performance. Thank you.

Comment: BERA and @Vince, I am facing challenges on dividing 2M polygons in Python's GeoDataframe since there is no Python function to do so (or I haven't found one). GeoPandas has explode function but works with multipolygons.

Comment: @martinfleis maybe post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get significant speedup if you have GeoPandas 0.8 and PyGEOS installed ([geopandas.org/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency](https://geopandas.org/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency)). PyGEOS uses vectorized numpy `ufunc`s and can be orders of magnitude faster than standard shapely.

Note that PyGEOS will be part of Shapely 2.0, so once that is released, installing PyGEOS separately will not be needed.